# Confused about production vs development

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, networking, axios

Let's use a very common example: React app that communicates with an Express.js server.

In development: The former listens on localhost:3000 and the latter on localhost:80.
In the server-side code, we can define the "Allowed origin" to be localhost:3000. In the React app code, we can point our requests to localhost:80 and everything works fine, right?

This is where my confusion starts (please correct me if I am wrong):

I learned that once the React app is loaded in the browser, any subsequent requests that the app makes to the backend server (e.g. an Express.js server) will include the IP address of the client who initiated the request.

So the origin will be the user IP address and not the address where the React app is hosted?

How does one approach deploying such an application?

Should we first deploy the server in one DNS name, update our React App code to point to that DNS name instead of localhost:80, and then deploy the React app pointing to the server by its DNS name?

Doesn't that generate a "cross-origin" issue?

What should we define as the "allowed origin" in this case? If the requests are coming from the IP address then it should be able to receive requests from anywhere, right? But setting the origin to "*" seems to be considered a bad practice, so what do we do then?

Also, if the requests are coming from the user IP address, then why is it that, in production, the origin is localhost:3000 and not just localhost?

Comment: your're confusing the client IP with the origin domain for CORS.  The Client IP has nothing to do with CORS.  "What should we define as the "allowed origin" in this case?" the DNS name of the react website should be an allowed origin of the backend API server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An "allowed-origin" is referring to websites that are allowed to send requests to your backend. [Here](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cors/access-control-allow-origin) is more info on that.

In your example, the React app (served on localhost:3000 in your browser) will make requests to the backend (served on localhost:80 on your server/computer). Hence, the "allowed-origin" in this case is "localhost:3000".

Now, **a development environment may mean just localhost** but also a designated DNS with the purpose of testing deployed code from both backend and frontend. This is mostly a sandbox for devs to develop new features and fix bugs.

**A production environment is what clients use** and should not have untested code deployed on. This has a designated DNS that is used by the client.

For example, what we see on Facebook is a production environment. The developers at Meta obviously don't just add code that is not yet finished so they need a development environment to test stuff out. When that stuff is stable, it gets deployed to the production for every user to see.

The allowed origin in this case would be [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com), the DNS the clients see.